# Scatter plot in R with ggvis: how to plot multiple groups with different shape markers and corresponding fitted regression lines

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot, ggvis

To plot the following in R with the `ggvis`package,

[image]

the code is

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggvis(~wt, ~mpg, fill = ~factor(cyl)) %>% 
  layer_points() %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  layer_model_predictions(model = "lm")
```

If I change the `fill` to `shape` in the above, there would be an error:

```
Error: Unknown properties: shape.
Did you mean: stroke?
```

**Why? How to achieve the desired outcome?**

Comment: If you don't use `group_by` and `layer_model_predictions`, ggvis can take shape. So, I am guessing, when you run lm for each level of cyl, something is going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to specify the `shape` in the `layer_points()` call:

```
mtcars %>% 
  transform(cyl = factor(cyl)) %>%
  ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>% 
  layer_points(shape = ~cyl, fill = ~cyl) %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  layer_model_predictions(model = "lm", formula=mpg~wt)
```

(Note that I use `transform()` to convert `cyl` into a factor.  This means you don't have to convert `cyl` into a factor in the `ggvis()` call, and the plot key is a little bit neater.)

---

[image]

Comment: In the `dplyr`/`ggvis` spirit, I would use `mutate()` over `transform()` here. `mutate(cyl = factor(cyl)) %>%`